# IsAssignableFrom is not available in TypeBuilderInstantiation

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

When I create specialized type from generic `TypeBuilder` it returns `TypeBuilderInstantiation` and not `RuntimeType` which doesn't support method like `IsAssignableFrom`. Is there a way around this?

Here is a snippet:

```
TypeBuilder stackTypeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("Stack", TypeAttributes.Public);
stackTypeBuilder.DefineGenericParameters(new[] {"T"});
var specializedType = stackTypeBuilder.MakeGenericType(new[] {typeof (int)});
```

Here `specializedType` is instance of `TypeBuilderInstantiation`, so following code will throw an exception:

```
bool assignable = specializedType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (int));
```

In this example I can create a type with:

```
stackTypeBuilder.CreateType().MakeGenericType(new [] {typeof(int)});
```

which will give me `RuntimeType` but in my compiler, I can't create types at this stage.

Comment: RuntimeType and TypeBuilderInstantiation are implementation details of the .NET Framework, this does not matter. "so following will ..." Why would that follow?

Comment: "following code" I meant. Its fine if it returns false, exception - is the issue.